# What does "to light out" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "to light out" mean?

I've been given a text by a translator that uses "to light out" with the meaning of

> for example when a LED light gets turned off.

Is this a correct meaning?

EDIT:

One example:

"The lamp lights out when the heater is on"

Comment: The first time I came across this was when Mark Twain's *Huckleberry Finn* [**lit out for the territory**](https://ludwig.guru/s/lit+out+for+the+territory). In fact, I'm not sure I've ever heard it used "for real" in any other context except references to that particular instance. But I'd guess that essentially, ***to light out*** is just a quaint folksy alternative to ***to leave, to depart, to travel elsewhere.***. It's definitely an AmE usage though, not really part of BrE.

Comment: Where did you see this written?  Is there any way you could provide the full context?  FumbleFingers' idiom is the only one I've heard, but the phrase could mean something else..

Comment: No, to **light**, when it refers to an actual light source like an LED, only ever means *to turn on*.  There's no such verb phrase as "light out".  We would say it *goes out* or *turns off*.  There is a phrase "lights out", but it's a command meaning *Turn the lights off!* or a noun meaning *the time when lights should be turned off*.

Comment: As mentioned, "light out" is also slang for leaving somewhere—but it means leaving somewhere *quickly*. Where did you hear it?

Comment: It was on a document that was a translation from another language. I read it and sensed something was off. Curiously the "google translation" of it give that meaning https://translate.google.com/#en/ja/light%20out so I am guessing that was their source

Comment: @Andrew  for example when talking about a LED, the documents says "it lights out when the heater is off" or something like that. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. We say "turn the light off" to mean you deliberately turn it off. If it happens because of a power failure, of if the lights go off for an unknown (to you) reason, you can say, "the lights went out".

The closest I can think of to this usage is that if someone turns the lights off, they may say, "Lights out". This can also be a command, like when you tell children that its time to turn the lights off and go to bed. Places where many people sleep, like dormitories and barracks, sometimes talk about "lights out time", meaning a time when everyone is required to turn off their lights and go to bed.

Comment: How would you say then when a LED gets on? "The LED will light up"??? How about the opposite?

Comment: @KansaiRobot  "the LED will **turn off**"

Comment: how about "as soon as the lamp turns off..."?

Comment: Sure, provided that you have something to finish the sentence. Like, "As soon as the lamp turns off, you should turn the knob clockwise" or whatever. "As soon as" means that there is something that must be done immediately when the event happens. Don't use this when there is no urgency. "As soon as you see a pedestrian enter the cross walk, you must stop your car." is fine. "As soon as the light on the coffee maker goes out, drink the coffee" would be unlikely, as it implies that you MUST drink the coffee immediately.